# Will the generator be closed automatically after fully iteration?

Tags: python, generator

Do I have to write

```
def count10():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
gen = count10()
for j in gen:
    print(j)
gen.close()
```

to save memory, or just

```
def count10():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
for j in count10():
    print(j)
```

In fact I would like to learn details of lifecycle of Python generator but failed to find relevant resources.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to `close` that generator.

`close`-ing a generator isn't about saving memory. (`close`-ing things is almost never about saving memory.) The idea behind the `close` method on a generator is that you might stop iterating over a generator while it's still in the middle of a `try` or `with`:

```
def gen():
    with something_important():
        yield from range(10)

for i in gen():
    if i == 5:
        break
```

`close`-ing a suspended generator throws a `GeneratorExit` exception into the generator, with the intent of triggering `finally` blocks and context manager `__exit__` methods. Here, `close` would cause the generator to run the `__exit__` method of `something_important()`. If you don't abandon a generator in the middle like this (or if your generator doesn't have any `finally` or `with` blocks, including in generators it delegates to with `yield from`), then `close` is unnecessary (and does nothing).

The memory management system usually runs `close` for you, but to really ensure prompt closure across Python implementations, you'd have to replace code like

```
for thing in gen():
    ...
```

with

```
with contextlib.closing(gen()) as generator:
    for thing in generator:
        ...
```

I've never seen anyone do this.

Answer (score 3):

The `close` method for generators came about in [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/):

> Add a close() method for generator-iterators, which raises GeneratorExit at the point where the generator was paused. If the generator then raises StopIteration (by exiting normally, or due to already being closed) or GeneratorExit (by not catching the exception), close() returns to its caller. If the generator yields a value, a RuntimeError is raised. If the generator raises any other exception, it is propagated to the caller. close() does nothing if the generator has already exited due to an exception or normal exit.

Note the last sentence: **close() does nothing if the generator has already exited due to an exception or normal exit.**